# How to pass collation to UDF

Tags: postgresql, functions

How can we pass the collation to a user-defined function?

e.g. I can use a hardcoded collation (e.g. `"de-AT-x-icu"`) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(agg_1 jsonb, agg_2 jsonb) RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
SELECT  jsonb_build_object(
  'count', (agg_1 -> 'count')::int8 + (agg_2 -> 'count')::int8
, 'max', greatest(agg_1 ->> 'max' collate "de-AT-x-icu", agg_2 ->> 'max' collate "de-AT-x-icu")
)
$$;
```

and the test works:

```
select test(
  jsonb_build_object('count', 2 , 'max', 'H'),
  jsonb_build_object('count', 0, 'max', 'i')
);
```

We tried to use a text-argument,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2(agg_1 jsonb, agg_2 jsonb, text_collation text) RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
SELECT  jsonb_build_object(
                'count', (agg_1 -> 'count')::int8 + (agg_2 -> 'count')::int8
            , 'max', greatest(agg_1 ->> 'max' collate text_collation, agg_2 ->> 'max' collate text_collation)
            )
$$;
```

but this fails with:

```
ERROR: collation "text_collation" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

What is the best way to pass/use a collation in a UDF in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collations are database objects, so their name is an identifier.

You cannot use a parameter for an identifier, you'd have to use dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL function:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   format(
      'SELECT ... COLLATE %I ...'
      text_collation
   );
```

Comment: I guess it could have bad performance to dynamically create a full query for every function call - so maybe it's better to hardcode specific versions of the function, when we only need 2 or 3 diffferent locales. Any thoughts?

Comment: I fully agree. If you have very many very small statements, the cost of planning them every time can be forbidding, and using a `CASE` statement in PL/pgSQL that chooses between several hard-coded statements would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the answer of @Laurenz Albe, I came up with a working version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2(agg_1 jsonb, agg_2 jsonb, text_collation text) RETURNS jsonb
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    res jsonb;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT'
        || ' jsonb_build_object('
        || '   ''count'', (''%1$s''::jsonb -> ''count'')::int8 + (''%2$s''::jsonb -> ''count'')::int8 '
        || ' , ''max'', greatest(''%1$s''::jsonb ->> ''max'' collate %3$I, ''%2$s''::jsonb ->> ''max'' collate %3$I) '
        || ' )'
        , agg_1, agg_2, text_collation) into res;
    return res;
END
$$;
```

Example calls:

```
select test2(jsonb_build_object('count', 2 , 'max', 'K')
           , jsonb_build_object('count', 1, 'max', 'i')
           , 'de-AT-x-icu'
           ) as agg;


select test2(jsonb_build_object('count', 2 , 'max', 'K')
           , jsonb_build_object('count', 1, 'max', 'i')
           , 'C'
           ) as agg;
```

However, keep in mind that dynamically creating the query for every function call will impact the performance.

As an alternative, we consider hardcoding some locales - or maybe even use only the `und-x-icu` locale (see *23.2.2.2.2. ICU collations* in the [postgres-docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING)):

> **und-x-icu** (for “undefined”)
>   ICU “root” collation. Use this to get a **reasonable** language-agnostic **sort order**.